# Problems with Python3.4 in Docker

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, docker

I'm trying to set up Python3.4 in a Docker image and it is driving me mental. I've been having this problem, when I try to install a python module using pip I get this error in terminal:

```
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/tmp/easy_install-wd8wc868/numpy-1.10.0.post2/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

_configtest.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.
```

No problem, I'll try installing it, it installs, I run it again and still get the error. Maybe I should try out python3-dev instead?:

```
root@238d2de76af1:/# apt-get install python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-dev : Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.4.0-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.4-dev (>= 3.4.0-0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How the heck am I getting this error on a fresh Docker image? Here is my initial Docker file for reference:

```
    FROM ubuntu:latest

# make sure the package repository is up to date
RUN apt-get update

# install pip for python3
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip  

# install git
RUN apt-get -f -y install git

#Pandas is for csv parsing
RUN pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: Why not use the official python images and sidestep all these woes? Or at least take a look at how they did it: https://hub.docker.com/_/python/ https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/15798abb6cfb145344462a345db4b572227fb859/3.4/wheezy/Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're hitting what's currently a bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1503382

Comment: Good to know. I wanted to avoid using a Python image, but for now I have no choice. Thanks for the assist.